# Destination folder macOS

Tags: macos

Hello does anybody see any error in this?

```
[!] Unable to find the Xcode project /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/project/platforms/ios/C:\Users\Simos\project\platforms\ios\Project.xcodeproj for the target Pods-C:\Users\Simos\project\platforms\ios\Project.
```

I copied my project from my PC to my Mac in a usb drive. THERE IS NO C:\Users\Simos\ directory on mac. Why am i getting this?

Comment: Isn't what you are facing kind of obvious?

Comment: Please tell me. If you mean the Xcode project, there is one

Answer (score 1):

look at the part starting at `/C:\Users\Simos\project\platforms\ios\` in your absolute path-

```
/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/project/platforms/ios/C:\Users\Simos\project\platforms\ios\
```

How could you find C drive in your MAC. MAC doesn't have any partition or drive like windows. Fix your target and paths when transferring the projects from windows to linux or MAC.

As far as I can tell from the path, your project is in

```
`/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/project/platforms/ios/`
```

directory in MAC. So, fix the target accordingly.

Comment: Yes i knew that didnt seem right How do i fix it? Where does it get that destination from? i only copied the files to desktop

Comment: in your code or in your xcode target setting, wherever, you have the hardcoded path, edit there. Without looking at your code or project setting, it is hard to pin point the exact location.